# Setting custom time options for angular-jquery-timepicker

Tags: jquery, angularjs, timepicker

I'm using the https://github.com/Recras/angular-jquery-timepicker to allow time selection in an angular application. Its time options are automatically generated, but I want to set the options by hand, by removing some options. For example, let's say we show time slots in 15 minute interval, and depending on availability I want to remove some time options. How can I do that?

Basically, I want to modify the following list and remove some time options.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple example

View:

```
<input ui-timepicker="timePickerOptions" ng-model="someDateObject">
<button ng-click="incStep()"> Inc Step </button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.timePickerOptions = {
    step: 5,
    timeFormat: 'g:ia',
    appendTo: 'body'
};

$scope.incStep = function(){
    $scope.timePickerOptions.step += 5;
};
```

Note: This works if the directive is watching the options model for changes (which I checked on https://github.com/Recras/angular-jquery-timepicker/blob/master/src/timepickerdirective.js and looks fine)

Comment: actually, I dont want to modify the step, but the data generated such as 7.00AM, 7.30AM, 8.00Am, 8.30AM etc..

Comment: That is the step, determinate minutes between values. If you are talking about showing only some custom values is not soported (you will have to modify the directive). This directive offers options between 00:00 and 24:00 with step diff.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `disableTimeRanges` option from [jquery-timepicker](https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker) for this. Your options would then look something like this:

```
$scope.timePickerOptions = {
  step: 5,
  disableTimeRanges: [['3:00am', '4:30am'], ['5:00pm', '8:00pm']],
};
```

Of course, you could also set `disableTimeRanges` dynamically if you would want that.